# Помогите разобратся в Mysql, LEFT JOIN дублирует строки по 2 раза

Tags: mysql

Не пойму почему каждая строка дублируется 2 раза.
Подскажите в чем дело может быть

```
SELECT * FROM oc_variants_product vp LEFT JOIN oc_product_description pd ON (vp.vproduct_id = pd.product_id) WHERE vp.product_id = '40' ORDER BY vp.sort_order ASC
```

Результат на скрине. В таблице имеется только 2 уникальные записи

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: потому что применяешь left join а не inner?

Comment: INNER JOIN результат тот самый

Comment: что вернёт такой запрос: SELECT vp.* FROM oc_variants_product vp WHERE vp.vproduct_id = '42'

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Это опенкарт, дубли выходят из за двух языков, которые прописаны в oc_product_description. добавил `pd.language_id = '1'` и вопрос ушел.